# Can't get image to stay within div in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble getting an image to conform to the size of the div. I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3.

I'm attempting to create a row that has two side by side columns, with text in one column and an image in the other. I'd like to keep the row "above the fold" for a 1366x768 resolution, and so I've constrained the row to 500px high. The problem is that my image is 344 × 690 and won't shrink to fit the row. It simply overflows top and bottom.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="special-background">
   <div class="container-fluid">  
      <div class="row py-4 bg-p1" style="height: 500px">
          <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center text-white">
            <p class="display-4 pl-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 p-4 d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="../imgs/image-name.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.img-fluid is defined in bootstrap 4 like so:

```
.img-fluid {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

I've tried changing height to 100%, but then it stretches like crazy at different viewport sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Does hiding the overflow suit your scenario?

Create and add styling for class `overflow-hidden` to your column:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 p-4 d-flex align-items-center overflow-hidden">
    <img src="../imgs/image-name.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

And its CSS:

```
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will crop from the height of the image. The utility class [already exists](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/27268) in Bootstrap 4.2.

---

Update:

For fitting the image at any size without cropping it, use `object-fit` property along with `max-height`.

Add `img-fluid-height` class to your `<img>` tag:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 p-4 d-flex align-items-center bg-warning">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/344x690/690" class="img-fluid-height" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
```

And create its CSS ruleset:

```
.img-fluid-height {
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Also available in [this jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/x5r41kLz/).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to show the entirety of the image :/

Comment: @spikem I have added a solution that achieves that. Let us know if this suits you.

Comment: @spikem if this fixed your issue consider marking the answer as correct and upvoting it. By the way, the downvoter may reconsider his vote as well.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a static height for row, you have to set `height: 100%` to inner cols, then `max-height: 100%` for image and `width: auto`, for not to be stretched. Also set `margin: auto` to be always centered.

Code:

```
.special-background .row > div {
 height: 100%;
}

.img-fluid {
 max-heihgt: 100%;
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
}
```